# Why this Linq code always throws System.StackOverflowException?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, stack-overflow

```
 //A query to a local object
 var deletionCommands = commands
     .Where(a => a.Operation != Operation.Addition)
     .Select(a => new { a.Prestador.cod_prestador, a.Prestador.cod_desdobramento })
     ;
 //A Linq-To-SQL query
 var toDelete = db.Prestadors
     .Where(a => deletionCommands.Contains(new { a.cod_prestador, a.cod_desdobramento }))
     ;
 db.Prestadors.DeleteAllOnSubmit(toDelete);
 db.SubmitChanges();
```

The only thing that solved the problem was an explicit loop:

```
 foreach (var command in commands)
 {
    if(command.Operation != Operation.Addition)
    {
        var toDelete = db.Prestadors
            .Where(a =>
                a.cod_prestador == command.Prestador.cod_prestador &&
                a.cod_desdobramento == command.Prestador.cod_desdobramento
            );
        db.Prestadors.DeleteAllOnSubmit(toDelete);
    }
 }
 db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: It's really the call to AsEnumerable that throws an exception? Yikes - normally that doesn't do anything significant. That's without actually iterating over it?

Comment: @Jon, that was a simplification. Replaced by the actual code.

Comment: @Jeff now that I solved the problem with an explicit loop, I think it removes the blame from the commands object

Comment: @Jader, since you've resolved it you may not care anymore, but I'm curious: did you try your original syntax using the equality tests rather than Contains method? That is, did you try `.Where(a => a.cod_prestador == deletionCommands.Prestador.cod_prestador && ...` 
 instead of `.Where(a => deletionCommands.Contains(new { a.cod_prestador, a.cod_desdobramento }))`

Comment: @Jeff No, I have not tried since I see that the "Contains" method is the equivalent for a "direct comparison inside an explicit loop".

Comment: @Jeff I still care about this question, since my solution probably isn't the fastest.

Comment: @Jeff and your suggested code will not work since deletionCommands is an IEnumerable<T> and has no Prestador property.

Comment: I asked about `Contains` because you said this was a Linq-To-SQL query, and it's unclear what T-SQL the `Contains` method renders when you provide it with something besides simple types (or `strings`). All of the documentation I can find for the Linq-to-SQL implementation of `Contains` show it operating on simple types / strings, and rendering the clause as `WHERE ... IN` though perhaps it's smart enough to render it as `WHERE field1 = value1 and field2 = value2`. Can you get far enough to see the SQL? Oh, and one final question, roughly how many items will typically be in `deletionCommands`?

Comment: @Jeff the test load is of 15000 items, subsequential executions will run with less items.

Comment: maybe I just found a bug on Linq-To-Sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was really a bug, and was corrected in LINQ 4.0

http://damieng.com/blog/2009/06/01/linq-to-sql-changes-in-net-40

> Query stability
>   Contains now detects self-referencing IQueryable and doesn't cause a stack overflow

**EDIT** In .NET 3.5 to resolve the problem: When using 'Auto Generated Value' = True, then you must set 'Delay Loaded' to False - otherwise you get the recursion error.

**EDIT2** The solution above didn't work.

Comment: Where is that "auto generated value" and "delay loaded" properties to set?

Comment: When you open the dbml on Visual Studio it opens a visual designer for ORM. Click on a field (inside a class) and open the properties window.

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint on the last line, then run the code. Then when it stops on the breakpoint, add another breakpoint at the start of that chunk of code. Then continue in the debugger (step over). It should hit the new breakpoint, and you can examine the stack to see how it has called back on itself.

What's the implementation of the `Operation` property? Maybe that calls back into some other code in a recursive way.

Comment: Operation has no implementation (besides {get; set;}) and is an "enum"

Comment: Hmm... then I think your next stop will be Microsoft support... something about your environment is causing the lower layers of Linq To SQL to do something badly wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I think so. If I could reproduce this problem isolating other possible causes I could report it as a bug.

Comment: That was really a bug, see my response

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post already, but changing the Contains method to Equals worked for me also.

This fails with StackOverflowException

Dim iLottery As IEnumerable(Of Lottery) = From lottery2 In combined2 Where Not (From lottery1 In combined Select lottery1.NUMBER).Contains(lottery2.NUMBER) Select lottery2

This does not

Dim iLottery As IEnumerable(Of Lottery) = From lottery2 In combined2 Where Not (From lottery1 In combined Select lottery1.NUMBER).Equals(lottery2.NUMBER) Select lottery2